# Changing Columns DataTypes in a DataFrame and pass it into a UDF - PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm currently working on a problem that involves changing the types of several `Columns` in a `DataFrame`, but I'm not sure how can I pass it into a `udf` because the function I have created takes a `dictionary` as an argument and therefore, I don't know how to pass the function into a `udf`.

All the data types I currently have are of type `String`, but as I mentioned, I need to change them to different types such as `Integer & Date`.

my function looks something like that:

```
def columns_types_transformer(df, reformating_dict):
    for column, new_type in reformating_dict.items():
        df = df.withColumn(column, df[column].cast(new_type))
    return df
```

the dictionary I want to pass looks like that:

```
dictionary = {'date1': DateType(), 'date2': DateType(), 'date3': DateType(), 'date4': DateType(), 'date5': DateType(), 'date6': DateType(), 'integer1': IntegerType()}
```

My issue here is how to pass the dictionary with the correct types into a udf?
Another approach I was thinking of is using SQLTransformer for it, but also not sure how can this be done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder why you need a UDF here at all? Your code should work fine in order to change the dtypes of your columns.

Comment: @pansen I wanted a udf in order to put this udf into a pipeline, because using only this function can't go into a pipeline I actually managed to find a workaround using SQLTransformer

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using the SQLTransformer.

This is what I have done

```
sqlTrans_formatter = SQLTransformer(statement="SELECT CAST(date1 AS date), CAST(date2 AS date), CAST(date3 AS date), CAST(date4 AS date), CAST(date5 AS date), CAST(date6 AS date), CAST(integer1 AS int) FROM __THIS__")

df = sqlTrans_formatter.transform(ddf)
```

Hopefully it would be helpful for others as well.